# Number of solution of equation $16 \sin^3x=14+(\sin x+7)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ in $[0,4\pi]$.

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

Number of solutions of equation $16 \sin^3x=14+(\sin x+7)^{\dfrac{1}{3}}$ in $[0,4\pi]$.

**My thinking:**

1. Directly satisfy $\sin x=1$.
2. I thought of doing $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)\;$ but couldn't proceed further because I can't think of a function on the left side whose inverse is the right side.

Comment: As you've written it, solutions depend on the value of $\sin x$, so the period of $[0,2\pi]$ means you can double the count to get the solutions in$(0,4\pi]$.  This assumes you meant $(\sin x) + 7$ rather than $\sin(x+7)$.  I'd add parentheses to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=\sin x$. Then $$16(y^3-1)=\sqrt[3]{y+7}-2$$
$$16(y^3-1)\left(\left(\sqrt[3]{y+7}\right)^2+2\sqrt[3]{y+7}+4\right)=y-1$$
Then $y=1$ or $$16(y^2+y+1)\left(\left(\sqrt[3]{y+7}\right)^2+2\sqrt[3]{y+7}+4\right)=1$$
$$4(4y^2+4y+4)\left(\left(\sqrt[3]{y+7}\right)^2+2\sqrt[3]{y+7}+4\right)=1$$
$$4\left((2y+1)^2+3\right)\left(\left(\sqrt[3]{y+7}+1\right)^2+3\right)=1$$
But $$4\left((2y+1)^2+3\right)\left(\left(\sqrt[3]{y+7}+1\right)^2+3\right) \ge 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3= 36 >1$$.
Only solution $y=1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $s = \sin x$.  Then your equation is $16s^3 = 14 + (s + 7)^{1/3}$.  Equivalently,

$$4096s^9 - 10752s^6 + 9408s^3 - s - 2751 = 0$$

By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, there could be up to 9 possible values of $s$, but I'm assuming that you're only interested in real solutions, of which $s = 1$ turns out to be the only one.

So the question then becomes “How many numbers in $[0, 4\pi]$ have a sine of 1?”.  And there are **two** of those: $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $x = \frac{5\pi}{2}$.

Comment: How can we say that $s=1$ is only solution?

Comment: How do we know that the polynomial with respect to $s$ has only 1 real root between -1 and 1?

Comment: [That's covered in another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505308/efficiently-determining-if-a-polynomial-has-a-root-in-the-interval-0-t)

Comment: I'm a big fan of root counting algorithms, but merely referring (in a Comment) to a StackOverflow post doesn't justify your claim that $s = 1$ is the only real solution. More narrowly one needs to justify that it is the only solution in $[-1,1]$.